# Apache Ambari : Datanode installation failed while installing in existing cluster

Tags: apache, hadoop, ambari

I have created hadoop cluster using apache ambari 2.1.0 with 3 datanodes.
Now when i am trying to add another datanode into(existing cluster) it, it throws an error that

> resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum
>   -d 0 -e 0 -y install 'hadoop_2_3_*'' returned 1. No Presto metadata available for base

Delta RPMs reduced 3.6 M of updates to 798 k (78% saved)

Here is my web UI console log:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/datanode.py", line 153, in 
    DataNode().execute()

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 218, in execute
    method(env)

File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/datanode.py", line 34, in install
    self.install_packages(env, params.exclude_packages)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 376, in install_packages
    Package(name)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 157, in **init**
    self.env.run()

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 152, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 118, in run_action
    provider_action()

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/**init**.py", line 45, in action_install
    self.install_package(package_name, self.resource.use_repos, self.resource.skip_repos)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/yumrpm.py", line 49, in install_package
    shell.checked_call(cmd, sudo=True, logoutput=self.get_logoutput())

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 70, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 92, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 140, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 291, in _call
    raise Fail(err_msg)

> resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum
>   -d 0 -e 0 -y install 'hadoop_2_3_*'' returned 1. No Presto metadata available for base Delta RPMs reduced 3.6 M of updates to 798 k (78%
>   saved)
>
> Error downloading packages:
>   hadoop_2_3_4_0_3485-yarn-proxyserver-2.7.1.2.3.4.0-3485.el6.x86_64:
>   [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like there are two issues with yum and your repositories.

First I see the message:

> No Presto metadata available for base Delta RPMs reduced 3.6 M of
>   updates to 798 k (78% saved)

Try running the following command on the host that you are trying to add as a datanode to fix the first issue:

```
sudo yum clean all
```

Then see if you can perform this command successfully:

```
sudo yum -v install hadoop_2_3_*
```

If you get to the prompt that asks if you want to install (y/n) then it was successful, choose the no option, and retry the add datanode action from Ambari. If you get an error or some failure take a look at the verbose output to troubleshoot the problem further.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @cjackson, I'll check with this

Comment: I have tried as per ur suggestion and it worked upto prompt that asks if you want to intall (y/d/n). I went with NO.After that I have retry to install datanode using ambari, but result is same.Is there anything to do with that last line I have highlighted in initial question that no more mirrors to try ??

Comment: It's strange that the package is found when you try installing it via the command line but it's not found as part of the ambari install process. Try this. Install it via the command line (choose y instead of n this time) and then reattempt installing the datanode using ambari. FYI: No more mirrors to try is the error yum will throw when it cannot find a package in the repositories you have configured.

Comment: I have also tried the 2nd suggestion as well but unfortunately it didn't work out. :(
Error downloading packages:
  hadoop_2_3_4_0_3485-yarn-proxyserver-2.7.1.2.3.4.0-3485.el6.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

This message is there as well while manually installing hadoop_2_3_* package.

Comment: Updated my answer with some other suggestions.